# ProcessStart() can not find filename in App Service

Tags: c#, .net-core

This code runs fine locally, but returns *The system cannot find the file specified* when deployed to an Azure App Service (.net core 3.0).

I have updated the code with the feedback from the comments, but the error persist.
What am I missing here?

```
        var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(folder, @"npm\mapshaper.cmd");
        // Outputs: "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\MyWebApp\AppData\npm\mapshaper.cmd"

        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = filePath,
                Arguments = @"arguments"
            }
        };

        try
        {
            process.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return $"Running Process.Start. Path {filePath}: {e.Message}.";
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of having hardcoded path, can you work based on Environment variable for `AppData` using the code as `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. You can append the remaining path to form the path till .cmd file.

Comment: Thanks user1672994 I'll certainly look into that. But will it change the actual output?

Comment: You can not reply that AppData folder always points to `D:\local\AppData`. Also, for additional information - Files stored at AppData are temporary files and these are not shared among instances. If you want to make sure that files should be shared among instances then use the Persisted files which points to `D:\home` folder.

Comment: did it work with suggested changes?

Comment: Nope. See updated code, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

App service Does not support .net Core 3.0 yet. you need to deploy in self-container mode